# Residual vs fitted values (large outlier in predicted value?)

Tags: regression, outliers

I have attached a plot of residuals vs predicted values for a model i ran. I see 1 large predicted value (extremely large compared to the others)

is this a problem for my model? and if so, what can be done?

[image]

Comment: I see a very *small* predicted value, $<-2$. We can't tell you whether this is a problem. It could be a very good prediction based on an input configuration that does not apply to the other points.

Comment: @ Stephan Kolassa. Thanks for the input. Is it a sign if there is a problem with my model?

Answer (score 2):

What we can see from this plot is that the observation with fitted value < -2 is a *high leverage* point: that means it is merely *capable of being an outlier*. It has the *beneficial* trait of improving inference and reducing standard error. You can think about the inclusion of this point as producing a more comprehensive design by covering a larger range of $X$ values.

Despite the presence of this (high leverage or HL) value, the point cloud of observations > 0 *appears* to have the desirable quality of being symmetric about the line (meaning that the trendline *might* not change much if the high leverage observation were excluded). If the HL point were inconsistent with a strong trendline in the point cloud, you would observe a non-zero sloped trendline over a subdomain of the fitted values. At this point, the data are too noisy to say if such a line exists.

The counter example to all this is if the high leverage observation is also a high *influence* observation, meaning that this point is strongly "torquing" the trendline toward the direction that intersects a meaningful range of its value. Indeed, the point cloud may be independent and has, alone, a trendline with slope 0; yet the addition of the high leverage/high influence (i.e. outlier) changes the slope of the trendline through that point cloud.

You do not actually see such a thing in this plot. A better diagnostic graphic is just a histogram of the dfbetas. An outlying dfbeta would support the high leverage/high influence theory for that -2 fitted value.